# Julia/Dates : convert a timespan from "days" to "year" or "Float64"

Tags: date, type-conversion, julia

I would like to convert a timespan from "days" to "year" or "Float64"

let be at timespan `t`:

```
t = Date("2000-02-04") - Date("1996-06-04")
```

However each following lines give me an error

```
t/365
Float64(t)
parse(Float64,t)
convert(Dates.Year, t)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value stored in `t` and divide it by 365

```
julia> Dates.value(t)/365
3.671232876712329
```

Note however that this assumes that each year is 365 days which is not true. For some scenarios a more elegant solution would be to count the years assuming that the date starts at some point, have a look at the example below:

```
julia> d0 = Date("2000-01-01")
2000-01-01

julia> d1 = d0 + t
2003-09-02

julia> year(d1)-year(d0), month(d1)-month(d0), day(d1) - day(d0)
(3, 8, 1)
```